# Dialog para alimentar campo de Form

Tags: jquery, html

Na minha página existem campos que são dados tabelados, onde o usuário deve selecionar um dado existente na tabela

Para caso simples, estou usando o `<select><option>` do `html` alimentado com uma leitura da tabela via `php`, porém me deparei com um caso em que os dados de uma tabela são muitos. Com isso o combo fica muito grande e a página fica pesada para carregar.

Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir uma espécie de botão que chama um `dialog` que exibirá a tabela com os valores, onde o usuário pode clicar sobre o dado e esse ser enviado para o `form`.

$(function() 
{
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});  
 $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });

```
            <?php
            require_once('../../function/funcoes.php');
            ?>
            </head>
            <title>Dober System</title>
              <body>
                 <div id="container">
                            <form action="../../function/funcoes.php"" name="inserir_C" id="inserir_C" method="POST">
                        <div id="Cliente">
                                    <fieldset id="Cliente">
                                            <legend><b>Dados Gerais: </b></legend>
                                            <label for="CODIGO">
                                            Código:<input type="text" name="CODIGO" id="CODIGO" MAXLENGTH="4" value="" onKeyUp="javascript:somente_numero(this);" required/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label for="NOME">
                                            Nome:<input name="NOME" id="NOME" MAXLENGTH="50" value="" />
                                            </label>
                                            <label for="NOMEABR">
                                            Nome Abreviado:<input name="NOMEABR" id="NOMEABR" MAXLENGTH="20" value="" />
                                            </label>
                                            <label for="GRUPO">
                                            Grupo:
                                            <?php 
                                            $rs = mysql_query("SELECT ID,DESCRICAO FROM FINANCEIRO.GRUPO ORDER BY ID"); 
                                            montaCombo('GRP_cmb', $rs, 'ID', 'DESCRICAO',null);
                                            ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <label for="REPRES">
                                            Representante:
                                            <?php 
                                            $rs = mysql_query("SELECT CODIGO,ID FROM FINANCEIRO.REPRESENTANTE ORDER BY CODIGO");    
                                            montaCombo('REPRE_cmb', $rs, 'CODIGO', 'ID',null);
                                            ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <label for="TRANSP">
                                            Transportadora:
                                            <?php 
                                            $rs = mysql_query("SELECT CODIGO,NOME FROM FINANCEIRO.TRANSPORTADORA ORDER BY CODIGO"); 
                                            montaCombo('TRANSP_cmb', $rs, 'CODIGO', 'NOME',null);
                                            ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <!--<label for="DATA">
                                            Data Implant.:<input type="text" name="DATA" id="datepicker" MAXLENGTH="10" value="" />
                                            </label>-->
                                    </fieldset>
                        </div>
                </div>
              </body>
            </html>

            function montaCombo($nome, $rs, $valor, $descricao,$cmb)
            {
            echo("<select name='$nome' class='styled-select'>");
            echo("<option selected='selected'></option>");
            while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
            {           
            echo("t<option value='".$obj->$valor."' > ".$obj->$valor.":". $obj->$descricao." </option>");
            }
            if(!$cmb==null)
            {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($cmb);
            $a= $row[$valor];
            $b=$row[$descricao];
            echo ("<option value=\"$a\" selected>$a:$b</option></select>");
            }else
            {
            echo ("</select>");
            }
            }
```

Comment: Voce deve deveria colocar o codigo do formulário e o código do php q cria a tabela

Comment: Thiago, [esse edit](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16995) que está para ser aprovado é seu?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando 2 arquivos 
tabela.php:

```
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Linha1 -Valor 1</td><td>Linha1 -Valor 2</td><td>Linha1 -Valor 3</td><td>Linha1 -Valor 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Linha2 -Valor 1</td><td>Linha2 -Valor 2</td><td>Linha2 -Valor 3</td><td>Linha2 -Valor 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Linha3 -Valor 1</td><td>Linha3 -Valor 2</td><td>Linha3 -Valor 3</td><td>Linha3 -Valor 4</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

form.html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>TODO supply a title</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <style>
                    #dialog table {background: #eeeeee;}
                    #dialog table tr td{padding:3px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
                    #dialog table tr td:hover{box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333;background:#fefefe;cursor:pointer;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"> <span id="buscar">Buscar</span>
                </form>
                <div id="dialog" style="display: none;" title="tabela">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Linha1 -Valor 1</td><td>Linha1 -Valor 2</td><td>Linha1 -Valor 3</td><td>Linha1 -Valor 4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Linha2 -Valor 1</td><td>Linha2 -Valor 2</td><td>Linha2 -Valor 3</td><td>Linha2 -Valor 4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Linha3 -Valor 1</td><td>Linha3 -Valor 2</td><td>Linha3 -Valor 3</td><td>Linha3 -Valor 4</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

                <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "tabela.php",
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $("#dialog").html(data);

                        }
                    });
                    $("#nome").focus(function() {
                        $("#dialog").show();
                    });
                    $('#dialog').delegate('td', 'click', function() {
                        $("#nome").val($(this).text());
                        $("#dialog").hide();
                    });

                </script>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. É quase isso que estou precisando, porem gostaria que a tabela fosse demonstrada de outra maneira, tipo quando escurece um pouco o fundo e a tela foca na nova janela.

Comment: ai voce vai precisar no jquery ui no lugar de $("#nome").focus(function() {
                        $("#dialog").show();
                    });                                      Coloque : $("#nome").focus(function() {
                        $("#dialog").dialog();
                    }); e pronto ta ae